# ORM and DB archival

Tags: c#, database, database-design, orm

Suppose if i use a ORM for DB access. Its basically a windows desktop App, with client server architecture. Now  i am trying to build archival or backup restore mechanisms. Are these specific to the databases or this can be made general by using the ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could create a mechanism for archiving or backup/restore for the user's data with the help of the ORM and coding but it is overkill except if specific business requirements or infrastructure limitations require it.

In most cases backup/restore functionality is an aspect of the DB component.